# Assign different color to NaN values in Matlab images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, satellite-image

I am working with satellite images on Matlab and am writing a code for calculating Net Radiation. The output contains the image in form of a matrix with `NaN` values. When I try to plot it using:

```
figure
imshow(X);
```

it assigns the `NaN` values the same color as 0. Is there any way I can assign those values to be a different color?

Also, I want to save my matrix as an image, but in a format that its values don't get changed ... possibly ASCII. Is there a tool for converting matrix to ASCII?

Comment: Can you post a link to an example of the image - satellite images come in a variety of range and types. In addition what do you mean save your matrix as an image without changing the values - what is the reason behind that and can't you just save a mat file?

Comment: The first part of your question has been answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481324/contrasting-color-for-nans-in-imagesc

Answer (score 0):

If your X matrix, is a 2D matrix with values between 0 and 1 and NaN values, you can use the following command to change NaN values to for example 0.88.

```
X(isnan(X))=0.88;
```

but if the X matrix is 3D (for RGB) the answer is slightly different and this solution does not work.