# Matlab imshow omit NaN

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using `imshow()` to visualize data obtained from the difference of two grayscale images. The images are masked, i.e. each pixel 'laying under' the mask has the value `NaN`. The data are represented by the `parula` colormap. The problem is that `imshow()` treates `NaN` as zero and therefore the masked pixels are represented as blue. Is there an easy way to omit the masked pixels or to display them in a color that is not part of the colormap (e.g. white, gray, or black)?

I would prefer the solution to base on `imshow()` since it would be easiest to include into my code. However, solutions using `pcolor`, `imagesc` or the like will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `AlphaData` of the image object to be equal to `~isnan(data)` such that NaN's will be shown as transparent values.

```
R = rand(10);
R(R < 0.25) = NaN;

him = imshow(R, 'InitialMagnification', 10000);
colormap parula
set(him, 'AlphaData', ~isnan(R))
```

[image]

If you want a specific color, you could turn on the axes and set the color of the axes to be whatever color you want the `NaN` values to be.

```
axis on;

% Make a red axis
set(gca, 'XColor', 'none', 'yColor', 'none', 'xtick', [], 'ytick', [], 'Color', 'r')
```

[image]

If you use `pcolor`, then `NaN` values are already treated as transparent.

Comment: Good idea! This has been very useful for me