# Adding a legend when using imagesc, including white for NaN

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, legend

I have a 35x43 matrix of data with vales ranging from 1-6 and lots of NaNs.

I want to NaNs to be white, and the numbers to each be a different colour. I need a legend with the 6 different colour and labels on it.

I can achieve most of this with the following code, however the colours in the legend do not match the colours in the figure. See code below

```
    figure(6)
subplot(1,2,1)
imagesc(lut)
title('Highest Weighted Predictor variable for each Pixel')
ylabel('Longitude')
xlabel('Latitude')
caxis([0, 7])
myColorMap = jet(7);
myColorMap(1,:) = 1;
colormap(myColorMap);
M = jet(7); % Notice the 3, here and below
hold on
L = line(ones(7),ones(7));
set(L,{'color'},mat2cell(M,ones(1,7),3))
[legh,objh,outh,outm] = legend('First','Second','Location','Southeast');
set(objh,'linewidth',200);
legend('Forest','Shrubland','Savanna','Grassland','Agricultural','Barron');
grid on
ax = gca
ax.GridAlpha = .2
ax.XTick = [5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40];
ax.YTick = [5 10 15 20 25 30];
ax.XTickLabel = {'118^{o}E','123^{o}E','128^{o}E', '133^{o}E', '138^{o}E', '143^{o}E','148^{o}E', '153^{o}E'};
ax.YTickLabel = {'13^{o}S','18^{o}S','23^{o}S','28^{o}S','33^{o}S','38^{o}S'};
ax.TickLength =[0.0 0.0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the `NaN` values as white I would [use something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38851267/matlab-imshow-omit-nan/38851344#38851344). Then for your colormap, just use `jet(6)`. Then the colors will match up just fine.

```
lut = [1:6 NaN];

myColorMap = jet(6);

imagesc(lut, 'AlphaData', ~isnan(lut))
colormap(myColorMap);

L = line(ones(6), ones(6));
set(L, {'Color'}, num2cell(myColorMap, 2))

legend(L, {'Forest','Shrubland','Savanna','Grassland','Agricultural','Barron'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an alternative solution using a `colorbar` with individual ticks:

```
%// example data
lut = randi(6,35,43);
lut(1:23:end) = NaN;

%// parts of your your code
figure(6)
% subplot(1,2,1)
imagesc(lut)
title('Highest Weighted Predictor variable for each Pixel')
ylabel('Longitude')
xlabel('Latitude')
caxis([0, 7])
myColorMap = jet(7);
myColorMap(1,:) = 1;
colormap(myColorMap);
M = jet(7); % Notice the 3, here and below
hold on

%// colorbar
c = colorbar
c.Ticks = (1:6)+0.5
c.TickLabels = {'Forest','Shrubland','Savanna','Grassland','Agricultural','Barron'}
```

[image]