# matlab imagesc, set NaN color without changing colormap - the proper way?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

simple problem that I could not figure out how to solve *properly*. Here's the problem and what I gather from sources online:

- I have a sorted vector `a` including NaN values and want to plot this using `imagesc` - while specifying the specific color for `NaN` values (pseudocode below)

what I know:

- `NaN` values are usually the minimum values in the colorscale
- setting the minimum value in the `colormap` to my faviorite color `[.2 .2 .2]` should yield the correct plot, where `NaN`'s are grey and the rest of the plot has the default colormap.

Below my two attempts to get a solution for this based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481324/contrasting-color-for-nans-in-imagesc)

1. Attempt 1 fails because minimum value has same color as `NaN`:

```
a=[nan 1:10]; %sorted vector with NaN values
figure; imagesc(a) % display this
c=colormap; %get colormap
colormap([.2 .2 .2;c]) %specify NaN color
```

result:

[image]

2. Attempt 2 fails because minimum value is not actually the minimum value of the colorscale (here I guess `parula`).

```
a=[nan 1:10];
figure; imagesc(a)
c=colormap;
colormap([.2 .2 .2;c])
caxis([-1 10]) %set color axis minimum to below the actual values plotted
```

result:

[image]

Obviously I could set `caxis` to a tighter interval (e.g. `caxis([-.1 10])` to approximate the 'original' colormap, but this is just not the 'right way' to go about this... can someone point out how to do this properly?

PS: an easy way out is to set the `AlphaData` of the `NaN` values, however this does not have the flexibility of setting whatever color you want (in this case... grey)

Answer (score 2):

What about substituting NaNs?

```
a=[nan 1:10]; %sorted vector with NaN values
a(isnan(a))=0;  
figure; imagesc(a) % display this
c=colormap; %get colormap
colormap([.2 .2 .2;c]) %specify NaN color
```

You may want to replace `0` by something like `step=(max(data)-min(data))/size(c,1)`, to make sure steps are properly maintained when putting it in the data.

[image]

A simpler alternative is to user `surf()` with `view(2)` and stack it on top of a personally chosen background color. `surf` will simply not plot `NaN`s, leaving gaps, that will show the background.

Comment: yeah, this works, but only because 0 is in sequence with the rest of the numbers. If you set `a(isnan(a))=-99;`or `a(isnan(a))=-Inf;` as I tried before, this doesn't work.

Comment: Well, then just replace `0` by the next numer in your secuence, right? You know the length of the colormap and the range of your data, so its a division to know the step. Then just replace `a(isnan(a))=min(a)-step` to have the same effect.

Comment: usually this is a scewed and random data. I guess you're suggesting `step=mean(diff(data))`. This is not better than approximate the whole thing with `caxis` - upon close inspection actually, the minimum colorscale value `imagesc(1:10)` is not preserved like this at all. Correctly, it should be `[0.2392 0.149 0.6588]`, at least that's what my colorpicker says - in the given answer here I get `[0.2745 etc`

Comment: No, `step=(max(data)-min(data))/size(c,1)`. Its the step of data at which the colormap changes. You are then adding +1 color to the colormap, so add +1 step, and thus the rest of the colromap should not change.

Comment: Maybe its a bit more complicated than that, but its more or less the way. Alternatively, use `surf();view(2)`. That will simply not plot Nans. You can then pre-`surf()` a background color to show in the gaps.

Comment: ok, if you can put that into an answer it's good enough for me